# Regex for replacing commas only within brackets

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have an ingredient dataset and each row is a list of ingredients that's separated by comma, for example:

Oats (24%) (Rolled, Bran), Coconut (13%) (Coconut , Preservative (220, 223)), Brown Sugar, Milk Solids, Golden Syrup (10%), Seeds (9%) (Sesame , Sunflower), Margarine (Vegetable Oil, Water, Salt, Emulsifiers (471, Soy Lecithin), Antioxidant (307)), Glucose, Milk Choc Compound (5%) (Sugar, Vegetable Oil, Milk Solids, Cocoa Powder, Emulsifiers (Soy Lecithin, 492), Natural Flavour), Natural Flavour

I want to parse the file to replace only commas within brackets with a semicolon. There can be any number of brackets and any number of commas within the brackets. The result should look like this:

Oats (24%) (Rolled;Bran), Coconut (13%) (Coconut ; Preservative (220; 223)), Brown Sugar, Milk Solids, Golden Syrup (10%), Seeds (9%) (Sesame ;Sunflower), Margarine (Vegetable Oil; Water; Salt; Emulsifiers (471; Soy Lecithin); Antioxidant (307)), Glucose, Milk Choc Compound (5%) (Sugar; Vegetable Oil; Milk Solids; Cocoa Powder; Emulsifiers (Soy Lecithin; 492); Natural Flavour), Natural Flavour

Can I get some help on regex that will solve the problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?R` like.

```
i <- gregexpr("\\(([^()]|(?R))*\\)", s, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(s, i)[[1]] <- gsub(",", ";", regmatches(s, i)[[1]])

s
#[1] "Oats (24%) (Rolled; Bran), Coconut (13%) (Coconut ; Preservative (220; 223)), Brown Sugar, Milk Solids, Golden Syrup (10%), Seeds (9%) (Sesame ; Sunflower), Margarine (Vegetable Oil; Water; Salt; Emulsifiers (471; Soy Lecithin); Antioxidant (307)), Glucose, Milk Choc Compound (5%) (Sugar; Vegetable Oil; Milk Solids; Cocoa Powder; Emulsifiers (Soy Lecithin; 492); Natural Flavour), Natural Flavour"
```

Where `a(?R)z` is a recursion which match one or more letters `a` followed by exactly the same number of letters `z`.

Data

```
s <- "Oats (24%) (Rolled, Bran), Coconut (13%) (Coconut , Preservative (220, 223)), Brown Sugar, Milk Solids, Golden Syrup (10%), Seeds (9%) (Sesame , Sunflower), Margarine (Vegetable Oil, Water, Salt, Emulsifiers (471, Soy Lecithin), Antioxidant (307)), Glucose, Milk Choc Compound (5%) (Sugar, Vegetable Oil, Milk Solids, Cocoa Powder, Emulsifiers (Soy Lecithin, 492), Natural Flavour), Natural Flavour"
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) gsubfn** This can be done without complex regular expressions using gsubfn.  The regular expression consisting of a dot matches a single character.  Then for each string in the input character vector the `pre` function initializes the counter `k` to 0 for then for each match `fun` is run with that character passed to it via the `x` argument.  Within `fun` the counter `k` is incremented by 1 each time a `(` is encountered and decremented by 1 each time a `)` is encountered.  If the counter is not zero and a comma is encountered a semicolon is returned to replace the comma; otherwise, the input character is returned.  This is vectorized, i.e. it also works if the input `s` is a character vector in which each component should be processed separately.

```
library(gsubfn)

p <- proto(k = 0, 
  pre = function(this) this$k <- 0,
  fun = function(this, x) {
    if (x == "(") this$k <- k + 1
    if (x == ")") this$k <- k - 1
    if (k && x == ",") ";" else x
  })
gsubfn(".", p, s)
```

giving:

```
[1] "Oats (24%) (Rolled; Bran), Coconut (13%) (Coconut ; Preservative (220; 223)), Brown Sugar, Milk Solids, Golden Syrup (10%), Seeds (9%) (Sesame ; Sunflower), Margarine (Vegetable Oil; Water; Salt; Emulsifiers (471; Soy Lecithin); Antioxidant (307)), Glucose, Milk Choc Compound (5%) (Sugar; Vegetable Oil; Milk Solids; Cocoa Powder; Emulsifiers (Soy Lecithin; 492); Natural Flavour), Natural Flavour"
```

**2) Base R** A base R solution is to split the input into single characters giving a list of character vectors, L.  Then for each component, `chars`, of `L` create a counter vector, `k`, the same length as `chars` which indicates the number of `(` to that point minus the number of `)` to that point.  Then replace those commas corresponding to a nonzero `k` with semicolon and transform `chars` back to a single string.  Like (1) this works on character vectors.

```
L <- strsplit(s, "")
sapply(L, function(chars) {
  k <- cumsum((chars == "(") - (chars == ")"))
  chars[k & chars == ","] <- ";"
  paste(chars, collapse = "")
})
```

### Note

Input string s is the following.

```
s <- "Oats (24%) (Rolled, Bran), Coconut (13%) (Coconut , Preservative (220, 223)), Brown Sugar, Milk Solids, Golden Syrup (10%), Seeds (9%) (Sesame , Sunflower), Margarine (Vegetable Oil, Water, Salt, Emulsifiers (471, Soy Lecithin), Antioxidant (307)), Glucose, Milk Choc Compound (5%) (Sugar, Vegetable Oil, Milk Solids, Cocoa Powder, Emulsifiers (Soy Lecithin, 492), Natural Flavour), Natural Flavour"
```